# What does LayoutInflater class do? (in Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to understand the use of LayoutInflater in Android.

What exactly is the role of LayoutInflater, and how to use it for a simple Android app?

Comment: The documentation on developers.android and on public internet gives a lot for this ...

Comment: `LayoutInflater` allows you to create view from and using an XML Layout file, that process called, `inflate()`

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729036/what-is-a-layoutinflater-and-how-do-i-use-it-properly/51729037#51729037) one helps.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**What is Layoutinflater ?**

`LayoutInflater` is a class (wrapper of some implementation or service), you can get one:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

---

**How to use Layoutinflater ?**

You feed it an XML layout file. You need not give full file address, just its resource id, generated for you automatically in `R` class. For example, a layout file which look like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

saved as `/res/layout/my_layout.xml`.

You give it to `LayoutInflater` like:

```
  View v = li.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,null,false);
```

---

**What did Layout Inflater do ?**

That `v` is now a `LinearLayout` object <sup>(`LinearLayout` extends `View`)</sup> , and contains a `TextView` object, arranged in exact order and with all properties set, as we *described* in the XML above.

---

**TL;DR:** A `LayoutInflater` reads an XML in which we describe how we want a UI layout to be. It then creates actual `View`objects for UI from that XML.

Comment: Why is it better/other than View v = findViewById(R.layout.my_layout); ? (Sorry for the lame question I'm also a beginner)

Comment: @Mitulátbáti  `findViewById` is for searching an **already created** View.

Comment: Actually, it is converting custom XML layout in Java object.

Answer (score 13):

when you run `setContentView(layout file name)`, you can run `findViewById(id of the widget)`. You dont need to do something like `xyz.findViewById`. The context of your app is set to that layout file and all `findBiewById` call will refer to that layout file.

There are cases when you need to pick up one more layout file, like a CustomDialog, ListElement or a Custom Toast. At this time you wont want to create a Activity just for these small UI components, that that time you programmatically need to get a programmatic reference to your layout file, so that you can run findViewById on it.

Inflate, blows the layout like a balloon and give you the balloon for you to watch around it all the colors and objects drawn on it :). Inflate gives you the object reference to that layout to call findViewById on.

Hope this clears.

Answer (score 5):

**Some basics for LayoutInflater-**

- LayoutInflater is used to manipulate Android screen using predefined XML layouts.
- This class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.
- It is never used directly. Instead,
- use `getLayoutInflater()` or `getSystemService(String)` to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context.

Answer (score 2):

From the Android docs:

Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. It is never used directly. Instead, use getLayoutInflater() or getSystemService(String) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on. For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Useful in creating Custom Views

[See](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely to get closed but the role of layout inflater is to create a `view` from the supplied layout file

```
View row=getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
```

it is creating the view from the `R.layout.list_item` file and proving that `view`.