# Is there another way to implement data into activity besides an adapter?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-adapter

So I started learning Android programming recently and was wondering if there another way to implement gson data using retrofit besides using an adapter and a list.

So basically I have to make a full-screen activity with a few `TextViews` and ImageViews (so I don't need a list). Do I have to make an adapter and a `ListView` for something as simple as that or is that the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to make an adapter and a ListView for something as simple as that

No. You use adapter-based widgets (typically `RecyclerView` right now) when:

- The JSON is dominated by an array, and
- You do not know up front the size of that array

If, instead, your JSON is a simple object, with a well-defined structure known at compile time, you are welcome to use that object to populate simple widgets in a simple layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try to do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `ListView` and `RecyclerView` then you can use `LayoutInflator` to have some of your limited Views Inflated to the LinearLayout or some other Layout.

**Note:** But for that views to get selected and do some operations or to apply animations will be vary difficult for you.

Check here about LayoutInflator here:

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater

and here:

> [What does LayoutInflater class do? (in Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101903/what-does-layoutinflater-class-do-in-android/17101967)